# Find the mouse location over a bitmap control and display a rectangle in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, positioning, mouse-cursor

I want to find the exact mouse location of the panel's display rectangle. I have a panel and assigned a bitmap image on it. I searched long time and found control over mouse location option but it won't fit. Anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) event and exploit the MouseEventArgs:

```
//panel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(panel_MouseMove);
void panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point myLocation = e.Location;
    //Or e.X and e.Y
}
```

Comment: It's gives me control over mouse location ... Is there anything mouse over display rectangle

Comment: What do you mean by display rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MouseMove` event:

```
    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = String.Format("({0};{1})", e.X, e.Y);
    }
```

You can use `e.Location` or splitted values `e.X` and `e.Y`.